# Probabilities of various outcomes in infinite mountain climbing

Tags: probability

I recently encountered a problem that asked the following:

Let's say a mountain climber is one step below the top of a mountain. Every second, he has a 60% chance of taking a step backwards, and a 40% chance of taking a step forwards. He continues doing this for an eternity, unless he reaches the top. What is the probability that he reaches the top?

My understanding is that the probability of him reaching the top is 1, because at any given point there is a nonzero probability of him reaching the top, and therefore he will eventually be able to reach the top given sufficient time. Is this correct? If not, how could I improve my thought process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As stated, the answer is 1 because the first sentence reads "climber is at the top of a mountain".

Comment: The issue lies in your statement that "at any given point there is a nonzero probability of him reaching the top, and therefore he will eventually be able to reach the top given sufficient time." It really depends on how small this probability is. Do you know about random walks, recurrence, and transience?

Comment: I guess the question asks about him getting to the top *once again*.

Comment: Either that, or it would need to specify the number of steps required to get to the top.